# What should I change in this line? (Syntax error)

Tags: python

```
elif not in records:
      print('File was empty'.format(fname))
```

I get a syntax error on this line, specifically on the "in" part. Im not sure what is wrong so I would appreciate some help

Comment: Please show a full example. In this case, 4 extras lines initializing "records", whatever it is you are trying to test, and the "if" that starts it all off should do. And include the error you get. We can't show you how to fix it without these details.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is valid English, it's missing an operand "something"

```
elif something not in records:
      print('File was empty'.format(fname))
```